# Video background transparent using canvas / svg

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I am trying to change the background of video to transparent. I have red and use couple of solution but they did not work quite will with video I use from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVIzzGBeK0w).

The solution I use are 
1) https://github.com/m90/seeThru
2) https://jakearchibald.com/scratch/alphavid/

The both the solution is working fine with their demo video but not with the video I use.

If someone can explain about how is it working. So might be I can able to fix the issue.

Here is the result which I am getting.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several methods that are used. The best effect is the use of a precomputed mask (done during post production) that is added to the bottom half of the video. The video is then rendered to a canvas and the two half's combined to create the transparent frame by getting the pixel data and moving the a colour channel to the alpha channel.

The process is very CPU (for Javascript) intensive and only good for low resolution video. Plus you need to create the animated mask and double the size of the video. If you view the second example in the standard player you will see the other half.

The Second method used by the first example is to compute the alpha on the fly. This is even more CPU intensive but very simple to do. Again if you have low resolution video and a fast device it is practical. You are then faced with the problem of setting the thresholds for transparency, because videos use lossy compression you will have trouble with edges and the threshold colour.

Your best bet is to use a WebGL solution (if you don't want to do it in post production) and do the masking on the GPU where you can have a more complex algorithm and some chronological filtering as well. Though it will depend on the video quality, the type of background (single colour or static background). You could also find a asm.js solution that will work better. I remember seeing one some time ago, I will provide the link if I can find it.

Unfortunately JavaScript is not up to the job of high quality matte effects in realtime for the time being. It is a shame as the 2D API would only need a single additional global composite operation, "chroma-alpha" (move the mean source RGB to the destination alpha) that would open up so many addition canvas effects (which god do I pray to for that to happen?). For now you have to move every pixel in javascript

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will look for webGL solution for now. Just wanted to know in second method what is actually happening. I am very curious to know how it is working

Comment: They render the full video to canvas, then use `ctx.getImageData` to get the pixel data of the video. Then move the pixels from the bottom half to the alpha channel of the top half. Then the just display the top half. They use the same method as the first example. This is the link to the second video so you can see the complete video that includes the mask on the bottom half. https://jakearchibald.com/scratch/alphavid/compressed.ogv